# Can I mix 12 gauge and 14 gauge wire in the same 15 amp circuit?

Tags: electrical, wiring, code-compliance

I have 12/3 wire from a switch to 3 light fixtures; can I feed the switch with 14/2 wire from a 15 amp breaker?

Answer (score 7):

There's no problem, and it is permitted by code.  However to prevent future confusion I recommend marking the 12 gauge wire with a permanent marker or tape: "15 amp circuit".  That way nobody in the future gets confused or assumes it is a 20.

Answer (score 6):

Yes.  There is no problem using 12 AWG wire on a circuit protected by a 15 ampere circuit breaker. If the lights; or anything else on the circuit, tries to draw more than the #14 wire can handle, the breaker will trip.